# How to save in variable the name of a class found with selenium

Tags: java, class, selenium

I need to save a class name in a variable so I can assert it later on.The html code is :

```
<span class="act-btn-top-blick low stop-work">Спри</span>
```

I need to save in variable "act-btn-top-blick low stop-work" .

To find the element I'm using XPath :

`driver.findElement(By.xpath(".//*[@id='workingBox']/a/span"));`

Cheers!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can use `getAttribute` method.

```
String variable1 = driver.findElement(By.xpath(".//*[@id='workingBox']/a/span")).getAttribute("class");
```